Noun phrase with adjective
As I am not sure,I dare not to use this form and I want to understand that I can use this form or not.For example, my niece is now sixteen.She  has become tall and large.She is happy for her growth and satisfied herself.Now she becomes adult.In this situation,I want to express her condition and happiness.As an non native speaker, sometimes we easily don't know noun form of an adjective but we want to express directly that event.So can I use noun form with adjective as follow,
1.My niece has been satisfied since becoming tall.
Whether it is the proper use of "becoming tall" I don't know.I know noun phrase comes after since and adjective phrase can't be followed.
Can I use above a sentence?

You might say "You're all grown up now!" to a 16-year-old relative you haven't seen for a few years (implying she was a child when you last saw her, but she is now becoming a young woman). But it's not normal for Anglophones to mention growth in weight (becoming "large").

"My niece is pleased to have grown tall."

Thank you very much!@FumbleFingers and @Kate Bunting

Just so you know, after a dot (.) or comma (,) you need to insert a space.

Yes sir , I will take care of that requiring space. @Ivo

"Since being tall" is not correct.  You need to use "becoming tall".  The meaning of "becoming tall" is "change from short to tall" and you mean "from the time when she changed from short to tall".  So you must say "since becoming tall"

The rest is not correct.
The use of "satisfied" is wrong.  If you say "She satisfied her growth",  then it means that "the growth was happy".  But you mean "She was happy". You need to use "She is satisfied".
Culturally it is strange to talk about being satisfied with one's growth.  English people would probably not say this. Also "large" is understood to mean "fat". So in many ways it would be a very strange thing to say.  You might say "She's happier now that she's grown-up." But I'd want to know why she was unhappy as a child.
We might say "She is satisfied with her test result".  It means that she was working to achieve a good result and the result is good enough.  I might say that a body builder who is working to make big muscles is "satisfied with his growth".  I would not say that a child who has grown up is "satisfied with her growth".  She didn't do anything special to grow.


Thank you sir @James K

I don't have a knighthood!

In additional, I am not clear that satisfy meaning, I tried to use "her growth" as a emphasis.Now I accept your answer to use simple present but if I want to write that sentence without changing but by adding word "about or with",It would be also growth was happy? For example She is satisfied with her growth or She is satisfied about her growth.If it is the same ,I have to analyze the usage of satisfied.@James K

"She is satisfied with her growth" or "about her growth" are correct grammar.  But both are odd phrasing.  I shall amend my answer.
